# display Listbox max value (highest score) converting from string to integer

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently trying to figure out how to display the highest student score from the Listbox i.e the listbox displays the following message

"Name: Tom Score: 18"
"Name: Dan Score: 15"
"Name: Fred Score 12"

I want it to only display the highest score.

Whenever i try running it says that it cannot convert `lstlistbox.items(0)` from `string` to `integer`.

Sorry if my explanation is not very clear.

```html
Private Sub AddlistBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddlistBtn.Click
        Dim Name As String = StdName.Text
        Dim strformat As String

        strformat = String.Format("Name: " & Name & "  Score: " & VTotal)

        lstListbox.Items.Add(strformat)






    End Sub

    Private Sub LblStatusBox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LblStatusBox.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnHighestScr_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnHighestScr.Click

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim lstsize As Integer = lstListbox.Items.Count
        Dim high As Integer = CInt(lstListbox.Items(0))

        Do While (i < lstsize - 1)
            If (CInt(lstListbox.Items(i)) > high) Then
                high = CInt(lstListbox.Items(i))
            End If

                i += 1
        Loop

        MessageBox.Show(CStr(high))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
    Dim max As Integer = 0
    Dim result = ""
    For Each s As String In lstListbox.Items
        Dim x = CInt(s.Substring((s.LastIndexOf(":") + 2)))
        If max < x Then
            max = x
            result = s
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(result)
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if the score is 2 digits... you will need to code appropriately if the score is more or less than 2 digits....

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a string like "Name: Fred Score 12" to a Integer, you will need to parse the string first to have only the integer you want and then convert it to an integer.

Yo could do it like this, considering that scores can only have two digits.

```
Dim str As String = lstListbox.Items(i)
Dim scoreStr As String = str.substring(str.Length - 2)
```

Then you conver scoreStr to Integer and use it.

You could also have all your scores stored in a variable (i.e. an array) and then pick up the values from it.